# create users, logins and give permissions in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i created a login : `bob`

i granted him permission to create database using : `sp_addsrvrolemember 'dbcreator'`

This automatically creates a user under the login bob, & with same name as the login name.

```
Login - bob
user- bob
```

Is the user created in master database?

I executed this query : `select * from sysusers`, but i could not find any user named `'bob'` in the table. Why so?

'bob' has the permission to create database.

now i want to grant him permission to create table. so how do i do that?
When i am doing it using grant, then it says cannot find user 'bob'? Why so?

```
grant create table to bob
```

After that, i connected sql server with login 'bob' 
Then, i created a database : bobdb
i entered into bobdb. 
Now, how to give create table permission to bob in bobdb

Do i need to add a new user?

Answer (score 5):

The login is at the **server level** - you have a login on a server.

The user is at the **database level**  - you can define a different user for a single login in each separate database.

The user is created in the database that is currently active when you run the create user .... statement...

So if you were in the `master` database in SSMS when you ran that query - yes, then that user was created in the `master` database and isn't present anywhere else...

Answer (score 2):

Connected to any database as yourself...

```
CREATE LOGIN Bob WITH PASSWORD='<the password>';
```

That creates a server-level **Login** that has only the permissions to connect to any db as the Guest **User**. Now add the **Login** to the *server-level* dbcreator role and connect to the server as **Bob**.

Issue CREATE DATABASE, you will still only have a *Login* with the name **Bob**. That *Login* will own the database, which you can verify by running this command...

```
SELECT  sp.name AS LoginName, dp.name AS UserName
FROM    bobdb.sys.database_principals AS dp
        INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp ON dp.sid = sp.sid
WHERE   sp.name = 'Bob'
;
```

Because the Bob *login* owns the database, he should be able to run most DDL commands for that database. If a login owns a database, that login can do anything inside of that database, including creating tables.

Granting rights explicitly to *user* Bob within bobdb would be appropriate if you change the database owner (**ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::bobdb TO LoginNameOfNewOwner**) an account other than Bob. Then Bob can be added as a *user* also named Bob and then only grant that user the minimum privileges he needs.

For more information, see the sections linked to the page on **[db_owner in Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180977%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)**

Also, sysusers is deprecated after SQL 2000. Refer to the **[new system catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082.aspx)**.

Lastly, K. Brian Kelly posted a good summary of **[login/user mapping](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/archive/2009/4/21/sql-server-security-basics-logins-vs-users.aspx)** on the SSC site.

Comment: , half of my question is still unanswered

Comment: Your grant command is correct, but the reason it doesn't work is because the Bob *login* is the dbo *user* in the database. There is no *database user* named bob and **CREATE USER Bob FROM LOGIN Bob** will get an error message (**Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The login already has an account under a different user name.**) The Bob *login*, which is now operating in the database as the *user* dbo, should already have rights to create a table. You will only need to use **CREATE USER** and **GRANT CREATE TABLE TO** for database *users* other than Bob.